# How to add margin between radiobutton ant it's drawable?

Tags: android, radio-button, drawable, margin

This my current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F5F5DC"
    >

        <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

 <RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_red"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_dk"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:drawablePadding="10dip"
      android:text="Danish" />
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_en"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dip"

      android:drawablePadding="10dip"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:text="English" />
</RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I get this:

[image]

I would like to have some space (margin) between radiobutton an the flag (it's drawable). Is it even possible?

Comment: If you don't mind having the flag to the right of text, then its position is easily adjustable with `android:drawablePadding`.

Comment: Using drawableRight insted of drawableLeft makes no difference. Using this, there is no margin between radiobutton and text instead of between radiobutton and drawable.

Comment: Uhm..seems like you are right; I had tested that in Eclipse using Graphical Layout, for Android 1.6 to 2.2, and there was a raisonnable margin between radiobutton and text, but seems like from 2.3 the space is tiny, like in your picture.

Comment: @DixieFlatline try to remove layout_gravity and use layout_marginTop this approach worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can do like the following:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_size"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="100dp"
        android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:text="label" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case, where I have a custom drawable shape, adding `android:paddingDrwable` attribure did not work but adding `android:paddingLeft="5dp"` did.

Answer (score 3):

Where you are setting the image and the text give blank spaces before it.
for example: radiobutton.setText("      "+Text);.You will see the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to add space between the image and the radio button using the android apis. However, the answer to your question I think is to add some space in the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative Layout instead of Linear Layout it gives android:layout_margingleft & android:layout_margingRight to drop your radio buton & Images as well.

Also give android:padding="10dip"

Try it it will definitely work!!!!